# Is there a better way to format this Python/Django code as valid PEP8?

Tags: python, django, pep8

I have code written both ways and I see flaws in both of them. Is there another way to write this or is one approach more "correct" than the other?

```
def functionOne(subscriber):
    try:
        results = MyModelObject.objects.filter(
            project__id=1,
            status=MyModelObject.STATUS.accepted,
            subscriber=subscriber).values_list(
                'project_id',
                flat=True).order_by('-created_on')
    except:
        pass
```

```
def functionOne(subscriber):
    try:
        results = MyModelObject.objects.filter(
            project__id=1,
            status=MyModelObject.STATUS.accepted,
            subscriber=subscriber)
        results = results.values_list('project_id', flat=True)
        results = results.order_by('-created_on')
    except:
        pass
```

This is valid code, this isn't correct code, I ripped a similar chunk of code to give an example of the objects.filter section. Please don't waste time commenting on the other parts of the code. I put the try/except in there to force an indent to push certain elements on new lines(80 columns)

Comment: Try http://codereview.stackexchange.com

Comment: Don't use base `except`s. They might catch exceptions you weren't expecting.

Comment: This code doesn't actually raise any exceptions, so why do you have the try/except?

Comment: Function names should be lowercase, with words separated by underscores as necessary to improve readability.

Answer (score 2):

I would do this:

```
def functionOne(subscriber):
    try:
        results = MyModelObject.objects.filter(
            project__id=1,
            status=MyModelObject.STATUS.accepted,
            subscriber=subscriber
        ).values_list(
           'project_id',
           flat=True
        ).order_by(
            '-created_on'
        )
    except:
        pass
```

Use indentation to make the hierarchy more readable. However, this code isn't particularly nice. Using code like this directly in views should be considered an anti-pattern. Model `Manager`s might be a better option for such recurring code.

You might want to read http://dabapps.com/blog/higher-level-query-api-django-orm/

Comment: You need to wrap the entire RHS of your 'results = ...' assignment in parentheses for that to be valid Python.